# Facebook Graph API me/home returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm losing my mind. I'm trying to get the user's newsfeed, I have all the proper permissions enabled such as read_stream. When I go to the Graph API console and try and do a query on me/home, it just returns an empty array.

me/home was working a few days ago, and now it doesn't work anymore. According to their documentation, me/home is still a valid endpoint. Everything else such as me/feed is working as expected.

Could somebody see if theirs is working?

Comment: There is a bug filed on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . And I hope you are aware that it will stop working at 4/30/2015